# woocommerce sending the order to a different email address listed in checkout page

Tags: email, woocommerce, customization

I am working on my own woo commerce website, and based my business type, I have three sales Rep. I want to add a custom field with the name of my three Reps in the checkout page, and if one customer selected the name of the rep, a copy of that order will be sent to him.
Could you please help me with the coding?
Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far, or what are you getting stuck on? "Help me with the coding" is too vague to get accurate answers.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt attention to my request. I have created a custom filed name billing_repr and through a plug in that I have used. The value of the field is stored in "_billing_repr" and I can receive the value in order receipt when someone buy an item, but I want to check the value and if it was equal to the name of my representative, I can email a copy of that specific order to the specific rep. I have not done any coding, because I am not really familiar with the hooks and function that I need to use for this purpose.